# What's the best way to select an ordered set of django objects by a list of ids?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of object IDs coming out of Redis and I want to turn them into a list of Django model objects (or a QuerySet). The result should be in the same order as the list. Currently I'm iterating through and doing a `get` for each id. I don't think that's particularly efficient.

Django has `in_bulk` but that doesn't preserve the order.

The size of the list is between 10 to 200 items.

Comment: Do you want them ordered numerically by ID? Or is there a specific order that you have that you want to preserve?

Comment: I want them in the order of the list. Looking back at my question, it' wasn't explicit. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manager.in_bulk just returns a dictionary, so there's no way to force it to have a specific order.

If all you want is a list of objects matching a list of IDs, ordered by ID, then do this:

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
results = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).order_by('id')
```

It may not be as efficient as `.in_bulk()`, but it's a lot better than querying one at a time.

If you want a very specific order, though -- say "in the order that Redis returned them" -- there's no way to get the database itself to do that. By their nature, relational databases return an unordered set of rows, unless you apply an ordering, but that ordering has to be based on the fields of the database.

Your best bet at that point, then, is to use `.in_bulk()` to get a dictionary of objects, keyed on ID, and then do lookups into that dictionary to build up a list in the order that you need:

**Edited:** If you're going to re-order the results, you should guard against the possibility that some of your requested IDs were not returned by the database. You can use results.get(id, None) to safely index into the dictionary, and filter() to remove the empty items from the list.

```
id_list = [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]

# Get all of the items from the database
results = MyModel.objects.in_bulk(id_list)

# re-order the results into the order specified by id_list
ordered_results = [results.get(id,None) for id in id_list]

# remove None items from the ordered results
filtered_results = filter(None, ordered_results)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [in field lookp](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Model.objects.filter(pk__in = id_list)

Comment: Does that preserve ordering? I don't think it does.

Comment: It doesn't; it returns them in the database's natural ordering (or whatever you have defined in the model) -- You have to re-order client-side; see my answer above.